# How can I make two windows show at the same time?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a game with pygame and face recognition. In order to do that I need to windows open. The one with the face recognizing one and one with the game one. But when I imported the face_recog.py , the game window wouldn't show until the face_recog would be closed. What should I do??

I tried importing in side the while of the game.py file

...python game.py code

```
   import pygame
   import face_recog
   from background import *


  FRAME=0

class Game:
   def __init__(self):
      self.width=900
       self.height=600
      self.screen=pygame.display.set_mode((self.width,self.height))
      self.clock=pygame.time.Clock()
      self.fire_rect=[530,40]

def main(self):
    global FRAME
    #sprite 그룹 생성
    self.all_sprites=pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.platforms=pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.player_group=pygame.sprite.Group()

    pygame.init()

    #sprite 그룹에 sprite 추가
    self.player1=Player((self.width/2,self.height/2),self)
    self.all_sprites.add(self.player1)
    self.player_group.add(self.player1)


    #배경 벽 불러옴
    for plat in PlatformList:
        p=Platform(*plat)
        self.all_sprites.add(p)
        self.platforms.add(p)

    #초기화
    trap1=trap(self)
    background_=background(self.width,self.height)
    item_=item(self)
    self.shot_=shot(self.screen,self)
    item_.item_display(self.screen) #아이템은 사라질 수 있으므로 while 밖

    while True:
        #settings
        time=self.clock.tick(60)
        FRAME+=1
        self.screen.fill((255,193,158))

        #배경 그림
        background_.background(self.screen)
        #item_.item_display(self.screen)
        item_.item_eat(self.screen)
        trap1.trap_draw(self.screen,self.fire_rect)
        self.shot_.shooting()

        self.event()
        self.all_sprites.update()
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit(0)
```

'''face_recog.py code 
     import sys
     import os
     import dlib
     import glob
     from skimage import io
     import numpy as np
      import cv2
     from scipy.spatial import distance as dist #입술 사이 거리 계산 위해
     import math
     import pygame
     from game import *

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #동영상 입력부분
 fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

 out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (1280, 720))

 predictor_path = 'shape_predictor_81_face_landmarks.dat'

     detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
  predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path) #LANDMARK PREDICTOR

   (mStart,mEnd)=(48,54) #mouth의 시작점, 끝점 번호
    MOUTH_AR_THRESH = 0.1

 while(cap.isOpened()):
       ret, frame = cap.read() #영상 읽어들임
      frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        dets = detector(frame, 0) #rects
       for k, d in enumerate(dets):
             shape = predictor(frame, d)
          landmarks = np.matrix([[p.x, p.y] for p in shape.parts()])
           for num in range(shape.num_parts):
             cv2.circle(frame, (shape.parts()[num].x, shape.parts()[num].y), 3, (0,255,0), -1)
    A=dist.euclidean((shape.parts()[61].x,shape.parts()[61].y),(shape.parts()[67].x,shape.parts()[67].y))
    B=dist.euclidean((shape.parts()[63].x,shape.parts()[63].y),(shape.parts()[65].x,shape.parts()[65].y))
    C=dist.euclidean((shape.parts()[48].x,shape.parts()[48].y),(shape.parts()[54].x,shape.parts()[54].y))
    mar=(A+B)/(2.0*C)
    mar=round(mar,5)

    if mar>MOUTH_AR_THRESH:
        cv2.putText(frame,"MOUTH IS OPEN!",(30,60),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7,(0,0,255),2)



cv2.imshow('frame', frame) #윈도우 창의 제목
out.write(frame)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): #key입력을 기다림, q를 입력받으면 종료
    print("q pressed")
    break


    cap.release()
    out.release()

  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Pygame can't display multiple windows at once due to how its event loop works. In your case, one window "blocks" the other until its event has been processed. You likely may need another solution. See these threads for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811814/pygame-with-multiple-windows and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105836/multiple-displays-in-pygame

Answer (score 0):

Your program is working inside a single thread. The first *while* loop keeps the current thread busy so that it can not handle the second loop (window) at the same time.

The solution is you must separate them into 2 different threads. You should create 2 classes, one class runs as main thread, the other runs in new thread.